# Button click event binding in playwright function in a new window electron js

Tags: electron, playwright

I am new to electron and other front-end technologies. I am trying to implement a desktop app using electron. In this app on clicking a button "Run Playwright" a new window should open and run the playwright function in this new window!

I used below HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Buyer-Assistant</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <button type="submit" id="btnEd" value="run playwright" >Run Playwright</button>
</body>
</html>
```

following the electron documentation!

main.js

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
function createWindow () {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration:true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })

  win.loadFile('index.html')
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
  createWindow()
  
  app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
      createWindow()
    }
  })
})

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})
```

electron preload!
preload.js

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const replaceText = (selector, text) => {
      const element = document.getElementById(selector)
      if (element) element.innerText = text
    }
  
    for (const type of ['chrome', 'node', 'electron']) {
      replaceText(`${type}-version`, process.versions[type])
    }
  })
```

by clicking on the button call this function in a new window
playwright.js

```
const { _electron: electron } = require('playwright');

async function runPlaywright() {
  // Launch Electron app.
  const electronApp = await electron.launch({
    args: ['main.js']
  });

  // Get the first window that the app opens, wait if necessary.
  const window = await electronApp.firstWindow();

  // Capture a screenshot.
  await window.goto('http://whatsmyuseragent.org/');
  await window.screenshot({ path: 'intro.png' });

  // Exit app.
  await electronApp.close();
};
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: how can i do to call the playwright function and it opens in a new window?

Comment: If you're putting that playwright code into the renderer process it's not going to work because you're limited to the browser sandbox. You'd need to set up playwright in your main.js where you can access Node then use your preload script to expose the functionality you need to the renderer script.